# jQuery second selector not working

Tags: jquery

I have this jQuery code that works:

```
    $('#info').on('click', '.border', function() { 
       $(this).children(".moreinfo").slideToggle(200);
    });
```

When I change the second selector to `.border h3` to only refer to the `<h3>` it doesn’t toggle. How can I get this working?

Comment: please post your html code. does `h3` realy have children element `moreinfo`?

Comment: post a fiddle if possible.

Answer (score 1):

This worked:

```
    $('#info').on('click', '.border h3', function() {
        $(this).parent('.border').find(".more-info").slideToggle(200);                                     
    });
```